# Windows phone 8.1 Binding only "Left" Margin property

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, mobile, windows-phone-8.1

I have a static resource:

```
<x:Double x:Key="dOffset">9.6</x:Double>
```

I want to assing this resource to the `Margin.Left` property in a Style.

I tried this:

```
  <Style x:Key="HomeButtonTextContainer" TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Margin">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Binding Path="Thickness">
                    <Binding.Source>
                        <local:CustomThickness Left="{StaticResource dOffset}" Top="0" Bottom="0"  Right="0" />
                    </Binding.Source>
                </Binding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But it does not work.
I cannot declare a Thickness as a resource like the following, the compiler complains about it.

```
 <Thickness x:Key="dOffset" Left="9.6" Right="0" Left="0" Top="0"></Thickness>
```

I can't derive from class Thickness so i had to make a Custom one that builds a Thickness(CustomThickness class)

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set only TopMargin. You should set all values of Thickness instance. If you don't want to change the other margins, just set them as zero.

XAML

```
 <Style x:Key="HomeButtonTextContainer"
               TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource dOffset}, 
                    Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">                   
            </Setter>
```

And you should create converter class returning Thickness instance:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var topMargin = (double)value;
        return new Thickness(0, topMargin, 0, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Edited:
Windows Phone doesn't support binding in the value of setter. Maybe [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/10/the-taming-of-the-phone-new-settervaluebindinghelper-sample-demonstrates-its-usefulness-on-windows-phone-7-and-silverlight-4.aspx) article help you.

Comment: This is the same i am doing in my question. I get this error: Failed to assign to property '%0'. [Line: 45 Position: 54]

Comment: If you give more details about error message, I can say that WP doesn't support binding in the value of setter. You can take a look at for workaround in my edited answer.